# Forward Fokker-Planck equation for stochastic differential equation with colored noise

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

It comes from an exam I took years ago, but until today, I still don't know the answer. Given a Langevin equation
$$
\dot x = -kx + \sqrt{\Gamma}\xi,
$$
where $\xi(t)$ is a colored noise satisfying $\langle \xi(t)\xi(t') \rangle=e^{-\gamma|t-t'|}$, prove that the forward Fokker-Planck equation is
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(kxP)+\frac{\Gamma[1-e^{-(k+\gamma)t}]}{k+\gamma}{\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2}}.
$$
I tried to search for texts like Gardiner and van Kampen for standard treatments but I could not find anything useful.

Comment: This is discussed in this PhysicsSE post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/213794/226902